# where should private and public keys be stored?

Tags: public-key, certificates

I am kind of confused whether should a newly generated key pair be stored in a keystore or in just a normal plain text file?

From what I read from online source, there are serveral explainations about what the keystore actually store.

some says it stores the certificates only while some says it stores the key pair **as well as** the digital certificates.

and if the answer is storing in a normal plain text file, won't that be insecure?

Comment: What's a "keystore"?

Comment: what is keystore? - According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystore

Comment: what is keystore? - According to http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/keytool-What-Is-keystore.html

Comment: TPM's are the place to store secrets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should keep the private key as safe as possible. How safe depends on the security requirements and risk assessment. A key store, such as a PKCS#12 key store or Java key store enables you to store a key protected by - usually - a password. This is obviously more secure than storing it as plaintext at the same location.

It is possible to mitigate the risk of storing in plain by using e.g. a thumb drive as storage device, and only use the storage instead.

Another form of key store may be present on a device such as a TPM, a HSM or smart card. Such devices usually protect against dictionary and brute force attacks by minimizing the attack surface - e.g. by blocking after a maximum incorrect log in attempts.

A key store may contain a certificate chains for private keys of the user, but it may also store *trusted* certificates. Trusted (root) certificates are for instance used to create TLS connections from your browser to websites. TLS can also be configured to use client authentication; in that case the key store contains both the private key + certificate chain *and* trusted certificates.

If a key store just contains certificates then it is usually called a *trust store* instead.

Use a key store if you can, especially those provided by the runtime system. A runtime system can often make use of lower level security mechanisms and provide a higher level of trust than mere applications can.

---

Note that some API's such as Microsoft .NET  act *as if* private keys are part of a certificate. They are not; although the public and private keys are part of one key pair, the private key and certificate are distinct. In Java the (E)JKS key stored contain a private key *and certificate chain* per key entry but they are retrieved separately.

These key stores are not really generic, they have been build for X509 compatible PKI (as used in browsers).

Comment: Also worth mentioning the Mac OS [`Keychain`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)) and the Linux/GNOME [`Keyring`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring) + whatever Windows does, as other common and viable keystores.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Right! amended answer.